# how can I be sure my system is update with latest security updates?

Tags: apt, security, update-manager, 21.04

am subscribed to ubuntu-security-announce list
I receive some emails mentioning that 21.04 has some bugs like

[USN-4929-1] Bind vulnerabilities
[USN-4913-2] Underscore vulnerability

however, since I upgraded my system from 20.10 to 21.04 (4 days ago) I never received any update
while am using software updater & pakcage updater but got no update at all

could you please help me here?
maybe there is somthing wrong with my system.

Comment: Are you running a DNS server, for which you have BIND installed?

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, **not all USNs are going to affect your environment**.  Just like a vulnerability in Microsoft Office only affects people with that version of Microsoft Office installed, it won't affect people who don't have Microsoft Office installed on their systems. (yes, a Windows example, but the point still stands).

As a result, you are **only going to get updates for security fixes in your OS if there are fixes present and available**.  This does NOT mean that every USN you see is going to affect you.  And it is **not unusual** to not see updates within days after upgrading, because none have been released yet for packages you have installed.  Give it time, you'll start getting package updates regularly.  Just because you don't see updates doesn't mean that you're "not secure" - it just means you aren't running anything that's received a security patch yet, which is perfectly fine.

---

In the interim, lets look at the USNs you're referring to and what they apply to.

#### [USN-4929-1](https://ubuntu.com/security/notices/USN-4929-1) - BIND Vulnerabiltlies

*Initial vulnerability release by ISC: April 28, 2021.*
*Initial patching by Ubuntu Security Team: April 29, 2021*

This addresses vulnerabilities in the `bind9` software - which is DNS Server software.

If you are not using BIND9 to run DNS servers in your environments, you are unaffected by this.  That's why this won't show up in your updates list.  Most people are not running BIND9 on their own personal systems and are more or less doing so in a server environment in the corporate world, so this likely is not going to affect you.

---

#### [USN-4913-1](https://ubuntu.com/security/notices/USN-4913-1) and [-2](https://ubuntu.com/security/notices/USN-4913-2): Underscore Vulnerabilities

*Initial patching by Ubuntu Security Team: April 28, 2021*

This addresses vulnerabilities specifically in the package and source package `underscore` - "Javascript’s functional programming helper library"

If you don't have this installed, you're not going to be getting updates for it.

You can validate whether you have updates for this by using `dpkg -s libjs-underscore nodejs-underscore`.  If you have them installed and the versions are at least `1.9.1-dfsg-1ubuntu0.21.04.1` then you're good to go, and you don't have to worry about anything.  However, if you don't have these installed, you're not affected.

Answer (score 1):

### Consult official sources

The announcement page for your mentioned vulnerability at [ubuntu.com](https://ubuntu.com/security/notices/USN-4913-2) shows what to do:

> The problem can be corrected by updating your system to the following
> package versions:
>
> ```
> libjs-underscore - 1.9.1~dfsg-1ubuntu0.21.04.1
> node-underscore - 1.9.1~dfsg-1ubuntu0.21.04.1
> ```
>
> In general, a standard system update will make all the necessary changes.

### Do what official sources tell you

In general, do a standard system update. Afterwards you could check which version of the offending packages you actually have installed locally, e.g. with

```
dpkg -s libjs-underscore | grep Version
```

### Caveats

This holds in general, but **there are always exceptions and individual situations**. Therefore, depending on your desired level of trust, you might want to investigate further possibilities and implications. For example, the vulnerability might have been already exploited on your system and the malware hides itself by various means, e.g. manipulating the `Version` output. **You can never be 100% sure**, but best practice would be to observe and estimate:

- What is the risk for the vulnerability to materialize on my system? Did you use the affected systems?
- How would you measure the infection? How much will that cost?
- How does the cost compare to other measures, e.g. completely replacing the system with a trusted one?
- etc.